# Nodejs `require('./file')` loads a dependency module when `file.js` does not exists?

Tags: node.js

I'm not sure if this is known behavior but it is really surprising to me. Seems like I've found that `require` behavior changes when nodejs is executed on interactive mode.

Given the current package:

```
{
  "name": "test-require",
  "dependencies": {
    "tiny": "^0.0.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

..and without any other file in that same folder, you would expected that the following calls will fail:

```js
require('./tiny')
require('./chai')
```

.. but when executed as interactive mode those will actually load the modules.

Now if those same calls are made from a file, then the behavior is as expected a `Cannot find module './tiny'` error

NodeJs docs says that:

> A required module prefixed with `'./'` is relative to the file calling `require()`. That is, `circle.js` must be in the same directory as `foo.js` for `require('./circle')` to find it.
>
> Without a leading `'/'`, `'./'`, or `'../'` to indicate a file, the module must either be a core module or is loaded from a `node_modules` folder.

link: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules

Comment: Could reproduce the same behavior in v13.3.0 REPL standing at root folder level.....

Comment: Reported to nodejs and they confirmed is a bug. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30808